# Is there any way to export a public key from pycrypto with a rfc4716 subject or comment header?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, pycrypto

I'm using pycypto but I don't mind using any library.

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4716.txt

I'd like to export a public key with a subject or comment header as defined in rfc4716 but I can't seem to see any functionality to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this code snippet simply works for me

```
import os
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

public_key = RSA.importKey(os.path.expanduser("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"))
```